# Can't submit Form action since it is hidden by overlay - I've tried Z-Index and Pointer-events:none; CSS/React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, frontend

**After layering on my css, my buttons in my react component are no longer clickable. I suspect that it's being hidden by the background/overlay. I've encompassed the buttons in a class called buttons-container and have used z-index: -1, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I putting the Z-index correct? Thanks!**

```
CSS Code 
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,700');

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-style: 20;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  // background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, aquamarine, green)
}

.buttons-container{
  z-index: -1;
}

.login-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  // width: 100vw;
  // height: 100vw;
}

.login-logo {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.login-subTitle {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 20px;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 40px;
}

.login-buttons {
  height: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: whitesmoke;
  // border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.login-buttons:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.dice {
  margin: 40px;
}

#register-button {
  margin: 10px;
}

#login-button {
  margin: 10px;
}

#password-input {
  margin: 10px;
}

#username-input {
  margin: 10px; 
}

.waiting-room-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.greeting {
  margin: 40px;
  line-height: 120%;
}

.drop-down {
  padding: 20px;
}


.area{
    background: #4e54c8;  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fb, #4e54c8);  
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
    pointer-events:none;
}

.circles{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
}

.circles li:nth-child(1){
    left: 25%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}


.circles li:nth-child(2){
    left: 10%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3){
    left: 70%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 4s;
  
}

.circles li:nth-child(4){
    left: 40%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 18s;
  
}

.circles li:nth-child(5){
    left: 65%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 0s;

}

.circles li:nth-child(6){
    left: 75%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3s;

}

.circles li:nth-child(7){
    left: 35%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 7s;
 
}

.circles li:nth-child(8){
    left: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-duration: 45s;
   
}

.circles li:nth-child(9){
    left: 20%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 35s;

}

.circles li:nth-child(10){
    left: 85%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 11s;

}



@keyframes animate {

    0%{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    100%{
        transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
        opacity: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

}
```

```
React Component
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
// https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

// import main containers for each page: login, profile, session page
import Login from './containers/Login.jsx';
import WaitingRoom from './containers/WaitingRoom.jsx';
import SessionRoom from './containers/SessionRoom.jsx';


import './styles.scss';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
  return (
    <div className="router">
    <div className="area" >
            <ul className="circles">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
            </ul>
        <div className="buttonscontainer">
        <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            component={Login}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/waiting-room"
            component={WaitingRoom}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/session-room"
            component={SessionRoom}
          />
        </Switch>
      </main>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether z-index is being used correctly to position the buttons so they can be clicked.

In the CSS you have

```
.buttons-container{
  z-index: -1;
}
```

This puts the buttons-container below the other elements - think of the positive z axis as coming out of the page towards the user and conversely the negative z axis is going in the opposite direction.

It looks as though you should have z-index positive rather than negative in order to put the buttons on top of everything else.